# Decorating a class with a non-generic interface where the decorator is dependent on the interface, not the class

Tags: simple-injector

I have a decorator that I want to use for all my jobs.  Jobs all implement the non generic `IJob` interface.  In order to run the jobs properly, I register the concrete class.  Now I want to decorate all the classes that implement `IJob` with a simple decorator. The problem of course is that the decorator is dependent on `IJob`, but `IJob` does not get registered as such.

Here's an example of the job

```cs
internal class HelloWorldJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<HelloWorldJob> _logger;
    public HelloWorldJob(ILogger<HelloWorldJob> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Hello world! " + 
            $"{context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.GetByCaseInsensitiveKey("tenant_code")}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Disposing Hello World Job!");
    }
}
```

and the decorator

```cs
internal class JobTimingDecorator : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IJob _decorated;

    public JobTimingDecorator(ILogger logger, IJob decorated)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _decorated = decorated;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var jobTypeName = _decorated.GetType().Name;
        var tenantCode =
            context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.GetByCaseInsensitiveKey("tenant_code") as string 
                ?? throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                        message: "Unable to retrieve the tenant_code from the context",
                        paramName: nameof(context));

        _logger.Information($"Begin job {jobTypeName} for tenant {tenantCode}");

        await _decorated.Execute(context);

        stopwatch.Stop();

        _logger.Information(
            $"End job {jobTypeName} for tenant {tenantCode}. " + 
            "Job took {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} to process");
    }
}
```

I know I could easily fix this with a generic interface for `IJob<>` but for this particular situation it's overkill.  Is there a way to tell SI, "decorate anything that implements `IJob` with this decorator"?

Here's how the job is retrieved from the container.

```cs
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container: _container))
    {
        var jobType = context.JobDetail.JobType;
        var job = (IJob)_container.GetInstance(jobType);

        await job.Execute(context);
    }
}
```

Where `context.JobDetail.JobType` is the Type of actual job to be executed.

Comment: Could you share the code where a specific job is used? How is this class requested from the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll have to do is, instead of registering all jobs by their concrete type, is create `InstanceProducer` instances for each of them that use `IJob` as service type. You can provide the list of job producers to the code that resolves a job based on its type.

An `InstanceProducer` is the place in Simple Injector where decorators are applied based on the used abstraction.

An `InstanceProducer` is what gets registered by Simple Injector when you call `container.Register<TImplementation>()`. Registering a collection of jobs using `container.Collection.Register<IJob>(assembly)` won't work in your case, because it becomes pretty hard to find the correct job again in the list, especially since you are wrapping the job in a decorator. You would have to iterate the entire list and look at the type of the decoratee. That's not going to be very performant.

But instead of letting Simple Injector manage `InstanceProducer` instances, you can keep track of them yourself:

```cs
container.RegisterDecorator<IJob, JobTimingDecorator>();

var jobProducers = (
    from jobType in container.GetTypesToRegister<IJob>(myAssembly)
    select Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IJob>(jobType, container))
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Registration.ImplementationType, p => p);

public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container: _container))
    {
        var jobType = context.JobDetail.JobType;
        var producer = jobProducers[jobType];
        var job = producer.GetInstance();

        await job.Execute(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get an error during verify that ```ActivationException: The constructor of type JobTimerDecorator contains the parameter with name 'decorated' and type IJob that is not registered. Please ensure IJob is registered, or change the constructor of JobTimerDecorator.
```

Comment: ah, I got it now.  I just needed to make sure a) I still register the decorator and b)exclude the decorator from the instance producers

Comment: By default, the `GetTypesToRegister` method excluded decorators.